# assign random values to all rows based on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to assign random numerical values ranging from 600-1200 to my column `df['size']` but based on another column. So if the value of the same row in `df['type']`is yes, the value of `df['size']` should be in a range from 600-1200 but if the value of `df['type']`is "no", then the value of `df['size']` should be a random value between 1500-2000.

```
df['size'] = np.random.randint(600,1200, size=len(df))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for select if matched `yes` or not:

```
a = np.random.randint(600,1200, size=len(df))
b = np.random.randint(1500,2000, size=len(df))
df['size'] = np.where(df['type'].eq('yes'), a, b)
```